# Windows 7 doesn't detect USB devices after hibernation

Tags: windows-7, usb, hibernate

I  have some troubles with my Windows 7. It detects USB devices (flash, mobile, etc.) perfectly if I didn't use hibernation mode before. However in case Windows wakes up after hibernation it can't detect USB devices. I just plug a device into USB and nothing happens. Only reboot helps.

MB: MSI H55M E33.
OS: Win7 Pro x64.

Could you give some advice to resolve the issue? 
Thanks.

UPD: I've found that USB connectors on the back side of my computer work properly. The issue relates to USB on the front panel.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what seems to be working on my Windows 7 Enterprise x64 installation (so far):

1. Create this key with `regedit.exe` (as Admin): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USB`
2. Create a DWORD 32-bit entry named `DisableSelectiveSuspend` and give it a value of `1`
3. Close regedit and reboot. Hibernate and bring it up again. Mouse should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, firstly, have you installed the service pack for Windows 7?

Also, have you checked the power settings for the USB device? It may be worth checking/unchecking the following options in device manager.

Open **device manager** > under **Universal serial bus controllers** > **right click for USB device** > **properties** > **power management tab**.

[image: USB power management]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just installed the service pack and tried to check/uncheck the options, however it didn't help me. The issue is still here. But I've found that USB connectors on the back side of my computer work properly. The issue relates to USB on the front panel.